# Multitasking network operations android

Tags: android, performance, network-programming, android-asynctask, android-service

I want to know what would be the best decision for carrying out several network tasks simultaneously .
My scenario is as follows :-
I have several words on my listview ( Maximum 20 ).
I want to search for all of these words simultaneously while displaying a "loading" progress dialog on my screen .
Now , I want the operation to complete as fast as possible .

I was thinking about two things :-
    i. Spawning several asynctasks for every request .
    ii. Using a service .

Please , help me make my decision .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Executor for running multitple tasks.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html.

Also check ExecutorService in the below link

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

An Alternative to asynctask is RoboSpice. Runs Asynchronously.Canhandle Multiple spice requests. Updates UI on the UI Thread. For more details check the below link

https://github.com/octo-online/robospice

Edit:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Check the Order of Execution topic

Quote from the above link

If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

**Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.**

Comment: Thank you for your response . What I am currently doing is spawning several AsyncTasks at a time for all the network operations(20).
Do u think using ExecutorService will be better (faster ) than that ? or RoboSpice ? Or anything else ?